# Playing Live RTP streams on android

Tags: android, rtp, live-streaming

I am trying to build a client on android that will receive RTP streams and play it.
I have searched on stackoverflow and Google, and found that MediaPlayer class can be used for this. But the MediaPlayer is used when a URL or a file is used as data source. 
In my scenario, my streaming server send RTP streams on a particular port of my client.
So, is there any way to play MediaPlayer to play this stream without writing it into a file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it out?

Your 'data source' for MediaPLayer is your rtsp link - rtsp://127.0.0.0:550/mystream.3gp

I have done this with a VideoView, MediaPlayer is jsut an abstraction of this, so it shouldn't be too different.

The MedaiPlayer will parse the rtsp url and start the Android RTSPEngine which will communicate with the RTP Server an establish the relevants ports to transfer the data.

Answer (score 1):

The method described above works - you need to supply the rtsp link (you likely won't need the port since RTSP defaults to port 554, not 550).

rtsp://se.rv.er.ip/mystream

Essentially an RTSP conversation occurs between the client and server (DESCRIBE, SETUP, PLAY) which will contain the information a .sdp file for an RTP broadcast would have.

You cannot receive an RTP stream unless the server sending it supports RTSP.

If you need more details, I'd recommend just running wireshark on a streaming client or server.  I found that helped supplement reading the RFCs.

Good luck!